# Finding quadratic factors

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

Show that $(x-√3)$ and $(x+√3)$ are factors of $x^4+x^3-x^2-3x-6$. Hence write down one quadratic factor of $x^4+x^3-x^2-3x-6$, and find a second quadratic factor of this polynomial.

My attempt:
$f(x)=x^4+x^3-x^2-3x-6$
$f(3^\frac12)=(3^\frac12)^4+(3^\frac12)^3-(3^\frac12)^2-3(3^\frac12)-6=0$
$f(-3^\frac12)=(-3^\frac12)^4+(-3^\frac12)^3-(-3^\frac12)^2-3(-3^\frac12)-6=0$

I know the first quadratic factor is $x^2-3$ but I don't know how to arrive to the second quadratic factor.

Comment: Synthetic division?, or however is it called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve all the questions in one formula: since you correctly identified $x^2-3$ as the quadratic factor, try [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) by $x^2-3$. This will

**a.** prove that $\pm \sqrt{3}$ are roots of the polynomials (since the remainder is zero),
**b.** give the other quadratic factor (as the quotient).

Answer (score 1):

We know that there exist $a,b$ with
$$
x^4+x^3-x^2-3x-6=(x^2-3)(x^2+ax+b),
$$
and comparison of the coefficients on both sides immediately gives $a=1$ and $b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try it like this:

1. Suppose $(x+ \sqrt3)(x-\sqrt3)$ are both factors.
2. Expand the expression above to get $x^2 - 3$.
3. Perform polynomial long division with $x^2 -3$.
4. You will get $x^2 + x + 2$ as the second quadratic factor.
5. Re-expanding the quadratic factors $(x^2 -3)(x^2 +x+2)$ gives the     original quartic polynomial. I uploaded a picture of my work with this reply.

[image]